# SMTP Address of the Sender of a Mail Item

Tags: c#, email, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

I have created a plugin for Outlook 2016.

To get the sender's SMTP address, I am following [How to: Get the SMTP Address of the Sender of a Mail Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184624.aspx)

Which recently start breaking when it try to do below line

```
if (sender.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
    || sender.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry)
```

> Message = "The operation failed." StackTrace = "at  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry.get_AddressEntryUserType()\r\n   at ....."
>   ErrorCode = -1802485755

Comment: please learn proper formatting of code when posting a question that includes your code snippets

Comment: @MethodMan can you include the reference that describes proper code formatting?

Comment: You are getting this error when testing `sender.AddressEntryUserType`

Comment: @domenicr Yes, it gives the exception there